# From Lua tables to Java data types

Tags: java, lua

I recently passed from Lua to Java and it's not easy to find how to do the same thing in Java.
I want to associate an object to a key. That object is some sort of array with 4 fields and different data types.

```
pseudocode:

SomeTypeOfObject = { String, int, int, int }
I will access it this way:
SomeTypeOfObject[0]
SomeTypeOfObject[1]
SomeTypeOfObject[2]
SomeTypeOfObject[3]

table = { key, SomeTypeOfObject }
```

I already know how to implement the table:

```
HashMap<Integer, SomeTypeOfObject> table;
```

but wich type of data I should use for my SomeTypeOfObject  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to store/retrieve the data, create an own class:

```
public class SomeTypeOfObject {
  public String field1;
  public int field2;
  public int field3;
  public int field4
}
```

Then use it in the `HashMap` as value, as you already mentioned.